# Creating a data class instance using secondary constructor with parameter which is another similar class

Tags: kotlin, constructor

I have a data class:

```
data class Person (
    val login: String,
    val password: String
)
```

Sometimes I need to instantiate it with my custom data, but sometimes I need to initialize my user by another class instance:

```
val authPerson = api.getAuthPerson()  // AuthPerson class has the same fields
val user = User(authPerson)
```

I wrote secondary constructor, but it doesn't work:

```
data class User (
    val login: String,
    val password: String
) {
    constructor(authPerson: AuthPerson) {
        login = authPerson.login;
        password = authPerson.password
    }
}
```

Can anybody advise me correct decision please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or if you don't want to use a factory, you can do:

```
data class User (
    val login: String,
    val password: String
) {
    constructor(anotherUser: User): this(anotherUser.login, anotherUser.password)
}
```

Secondary Constructors **[must call their primary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors)**.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a factory method:

```
data class User(
    val login: String,
    val password: String
) {
    companion object {
        fun fromPerson(person: Person) = User(person.login, person.password)
    }
}
...
val user = User.fromPerson(person)
```

or create an extension function:

```
fun Person.toUser() = User(login, password)
...
val user = person.toUser()
```